# iphone ios xcode 4.2 - EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

Well i'm designing an iPhone app which will play video locally. When I click the button in the simulator it plays perfectly but when it stops or when I end it manually it crashed and keeps giving me that problem.. I tried clean, build, analyse and run again but still the same. Any help?

My code is that:

MoviePlayerViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface MoviePlayerViewController : UIViewController {

}
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender;
@end
```

and the main bit in MoviePlayerViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender {
    NSString *movpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"think" ofType:@"mp4"];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                                     initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:mpviewController.view];
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [mpviewController moviePlayer];
    [mp prepareToPlay];
    mp.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [[mpviewController moviePlayer] play];
}

- (void)playbackFinishedCallback:(NSNotification *)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpviewController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:mpviewController];
    [mpviewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [mpviewController release];
}
```

Comment: Run your app using the Zombies instrument. It will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: How? In the new xcode is quite different. I searched for it but didn't find it yet..

Comment: If you go into your scheme settings there is a tick box for zombies. It will cause zombie objects that you try to access to be printed in the log. Then you can see what they are and fix them :)

Comment: Or you can just select Profile from the Products menu in Xcode, then when Instruments opens select the Zombies instrument. Make sure you're building for the Simulator as the Zombies instrument is not available on the device. When the app gets the error, you'll see a little box popup in the Instruments window, if you click the arrow in the box you can get information about the object that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making the movie player controller na ivar

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

  @interface MoviePlayerViewController : UIViewController {

  }

  @property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpviewController;

  -(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender;
  @end
```

Then you can do something like so in the implementation file

```
  @synthesize mpviewController;

  - (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender {
      NSString *movpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"think" ofType:@"mp4"];
      MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                                       initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]];

      self.mpviewController = mpController; 
      [mpController release];                                              

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinishedCallback:)
                                                   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

      [self.view addSubview:self.mpviewController.view];
      MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [self.mpviewController moviePlayer];
      [mp prepareToPlay];
      mp.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
      [[self.mpviewController moviePlayer] play];
  }

  - (void)playbackFinishedCallback:(NSNotification *)notification {

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:mpviewController];
      [mpviewController.view removeFromSuperview];
  }

  - (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.mpviewController = nil;
  }

  - (void)dealloc{
    self.mpviewController = nil;

    [super dealloc];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in the code, here are the fixes:

1> Remove `[mpviewController release];` because it is created using a method which returns `*autorelease*` object.(`[notification object]`). To release the `mpviewController` object declare it as instance variable and release it and make it nil.

```
if(mpviewController != nil) 
{  
[mpviewController release];  
mpviewController = nil;
}
```

2> As you have declared `mpviewController` as instance variable, there is no need to access `mpviewController` variable via `[notification object]` because its not there as you have not supplied it when you add observer to notification center.

3> Replace following line of code:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:mpviewController];
```

with

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

Explaination: When you add observer you are not providing any object information but at the time of removal you

So now your code will become:

```
- (void)playbackFinishedCallback:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    [mpviewController.view removeFromSuperview];
   if(mpviewController != nil)
    {
        [mpviewController release];
        mpviewController = nil;
     }
}
```

Also, in `- (void) dealloc` of this controller you should write similar code for releasing `mpviewController`.

Thanks,

Comment: I tried that but then it doesn't recognize the mpviewController.. I declared it with no errors but it still keeps crashing and giving me same error..